# Organizing workout info with hashmaps and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm looking to create a java program that will store a workout with each lift and reps performed. But I'm not exactly sure how to organize the data structure. I was thinking to use a hashmap to store everything with the hashcode being the date performed. So something performed december 24, 2013 would be stored at 122413. The element I would want to store there would be like an array of arrays, with each array displaying the lift and each following element would alternate between the reps performed and weight. 
Here's a visual example of that.

```
arr = [["bench press",10,185,9,195,8,205],["shoulder press",10,95,8,95,6,95],...]
```

So if I wanted the reps and weight performed for my second set of bench press it would output like:

```
You performed arr[0][1] reps of arr[0][2] for arr[0][0]
---
You performed    10     reps of   185     for bench press
-----
```

I know this can be done in python, but I'm not sure that it's available in java?
I'm having issues implementing as from what I've found the datatypes of an array all need to be the same type (no string AND int), which is actually okay because these numbers don't really have a numerical value and will just be displayed. But I'm also a little stuck on getting an array stored in a hashmap and building an array of arrays.

So, my question: is this a doable implementation for what I'm trying to accomplish? Or is there a better way to go about organizing this? I'd like to keep the data organized by date as I showed earlier if possible. 
Any help or suggestions would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think your question is fit for StackOverflow as it is basically opinion-based. I suggest you go to Programmers instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with creating custom data structures to model your scenario. For example.

Set class with a weight property and a reps property.

Exercise class with a name property and a collection of Sets.

Workout class with a collection of Exercises and a date property for when the workout was done.

That way, if you wanted to extend it to include food you eat that day, you could either add it to the workout, or probably a better option would be to compose another class of a Workout and food eaten.

That way you open the possibility to draw correlations between how well you trained on a certain day with what you eat.

-- I'm a C# developer and I haven't touched Java before so apologies if the Syntax or the types aren't correct --

```
public class Set {
    public  Set()
    {
        this._weight = 0;
        this._reps = new ArrayList<int>();
    }
    private BigDecimal _weight;
    private List<int> _reps;
    // implement public properties / methods
}

public class Exercise {
    public Exercise()
    {
        this._name = "";
        this._sets = new ArrayList<Set>();
    }
    private String _name;
    private List<Set> _sets;
    // implement public properties / methods
}

public class Workout {
    public Workout(Date workoutDate)
    {
        this._date = workoutDate;
        this._exercises = new ArrayList<Exercise>
    }
    private Date _date;
    private List<Exercise> _exercises;
    // implement public properties / methods
}
```

Then you'd be able to store a List and order them by Date using a custom implementation of `Comparator<Workout>`